# Interaction with user in C (scanf())

Tags: c, scanf

I need

1. To ask user whether he want to use factorial function or
   fibonacci function
2. To ask him value.

How it looks:

```
printf("choose option:\n1 - factorial\n2 - fibonacci sequence\n");
scanf("%d", &a);

if (a==1) {
  printf("enter a number:\n");
  scanf("%d", &x);
  return factorial(x); 
}

if (a==2) {
  printf("enter a number of sequence:\n");
  scanf("%d", &y);
  return fibonacci(y); 
}
```

Problem: the first part works but the second does not. `Error: 'exit status 120'`

What is wrong?

Comment: 1) Post the code for your fibonnaci() function, it might have a bug.  2) Which number did you enter and pass to your fibonacci() function ?  
Please answer BOTH those questions. You should do some basic debugging in your program. e.g. you would want to be 100% sure that the number you enter is the number your program actually processes. So e.g. after `scanf("%d", &y);` add a line that prints that number back to you so you can verify it, e.g. `printf("Calling fibbonaci() with y=%d\n", y);`

Comment: Returning a non-zero value (`return factorial(x)`, `return fibonacci(y)`) from `main()`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a [MCVE]. Also take the [tour] and read this: [ask].

Answer (score -3):

```
/*
For first,  variable 'a' should be declared as  integer:
*/
int a = 0;
/*
  Further, when you read keystrokes, you get ascii code of a character.
  Remember:'1' != 1
   Your 'if' statement should be different:
*/  
if (a == '1') {... }   /* note single quote characters around '1' and '2' */
else if (a == '2') {... }
else
{
   /* if user press something that is not '1' or '2' */
     printf("Wrong choice!\n");
     exit(1);
}
```

Comment: This is wrong and misleading; OP is scanning using `%d` which does not return character values.

Comment: Indeed, format string for scanf should be "%c".  The point of my answer is that wrong inputs shold be handled. Thank you!